# Probability of Brownian motion being enveloped by square root

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I am trying to calculate the following probability:

$$P\{W_t \leq a\sqrt{t} \quad \forall{t} \leq T\}$$
where $a, T > 0$.

By scaling property, for any $b > 0$, this probability is equal to
$$P\{bW_{\frac{t}{b^2}} \leq a\sqrt{t} \quad \forall{t} \leq T\}$$
Defining $u =\frac{t}{b^2}$,
$$P\{W_u \leq a\sqrt{u} \quad \forall{u} \leq \frac{T}{b^2}\}$$

I choose $b = \sqrt{T}$ to get
$$P\{W_t \leq a\sqrt{t} \quad \forall{t} \leq T\} = P\{W_t \leq a\sqrt{t} \quad \forall{t} \leq 1\}$$

By time reversal,

$$\begin{eqnarray} 
P\{W_t \leq a\sqrt{t} \quad \forall{t} \leq 1\} &=&  P\{tW_{\frac{1}{t}} \leq a\sqrt{t} \quad \forall{t} \leq 1\}      \nonumber \\
&=&  P\{W_t \leq a\sqrt{t} \quad \forall{t} \geq 1\} \nonumber \\
\end{eqnarray}$$

But this implies

$$P\{W_t \leq a\sqrt{t} \quad \forall{t} \geq 0\} = 2P\{W_t \leq a\sqrt{t} \quad \forall{t} \leq 1\}$$
Hence $$P\{W_t \leq a\sqrt{t} \quad \forall{t} \leq 1\} = 0$$

I am looking for alternative approaches to this problem (e.g. slick one-liners, convoluted derivations using martingale theory)

Answer (score 1):

By law of iterated logarithm we have a.s. $\limsup_{t\to 0^+}\frac{W_t}{(2t \ln|\ln t|)^{1/2}}=1$ (ref.: [Schilling](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/9783110741278/html?lang=en), Corollary 12.2.) so
$$\limsup_{t\to 0^+}\frac{W_t}{t^{1/2}}=\limsup_{t\to 0^+}\frac{W_t}{(2t \ln|\ln t|)^{1/2}}(2 \ln|\ln t|)^{1/2}=\infty$$
a.s. So the probability of the event is zero.